# ADF - af:InputListOfValues set to null when mapping a lov attribute to vo attribute

Tags: oracle-adf

I added a field in search criteria and assigned it to the `af:InputListOfValues` to map the `lov` attribute to one of the view attribute. Its displays the `lov` values in popup but after selecting the value it automatically set it to be null.

Note: Data type of my VO and LOV attribute are same.
LOV attribute is DB object whereas my VO attribute is transient and set it to updatable always.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a server event happens, your VO query would get re-executed which means your transient attribute would get set to null - this means it won't match any value from the LOV. 
You might need to make the VO attribute queryable or calculated and map it to some column or expression from the base VO query